# Sport ausüben vs. Sport treiben

Tags: meaning

Ich habe gehört, dass man *Sport ausüben* benutzt wenn eine Sportart unbekannt ist. Falls die Sportart bekannt ist, nimmt man *Sport treiben* in Anspruch. Ist das richtig? Wenn nicht, bitte sagen Sie mir den Unterscheid zwischen den beiden mit Beispielen.

Danke für Ihre Antworten!

Comment: Die Wörter *ausüben*, *treiben* und *sagen* sind Verben, daher darf man sie im Inneren eines Satzes nicht groß schreiben. Auch *beiden* ist kein Substantiv (sondern ein Indefinitpronomen). Aber nur Substantive darf man (muss man sogar) im Inneren eines Satzes großschreiben. Ich habe die entsprechenden Korrekturen vorgenommen.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Dann kann man Grüße auch gleich mit rausnehmen. Dass man nicht nur wegen der Grüße editiert verstehe ich ja, aber wenn man schon dabei ist ...

Comment: Du meinst mit »Grüße« offenbar den Dank für die Antworten. Das sind keine Grüße, sondern ist eine Höflichkeitsfloskel. Es kommt ohnehin immer seltener vor, das Leute höflich sind. Wenn man dann auch noch den sprachlich vollkommen richtigen Satz »Danke für Ihre Antworten!« rauslöscht sendet man ein völlig falsches Signal. Daher habe ich deine Änderung wieder rückgängig gemacht.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Das eine Verb ist **etwas ausüben**. Es bedeutet, dass man eine Sache aus *Übung*, also Beruf oder Gewohnheit tut.

> Er übt den Beruf des Feuerwehrmanns aus.
>
> Im Verein Schwarz-Weiß können Sie Tennis und Badminton ausüben.

Die Tätigkeit ist meistens ein Beruf oder eine Sportart.

---

Das Verb **etwas treiben** heißt hingegen, dass man eine Sache immer und immer wieder tut.

> Sie treibt Sport.
>
> Er treibt sich herum.
>
> Du treibst es zu bunt.

Sätze mit dem Verb *treiben* sind meist sehr idiomatisch. Vorsicht: *Es treiben.* bedeutet *Sex haben.*

Comment: Ist es möglich, den Verb machen, zu benutzen? Ich habe oft gehört "Ich mache gern Sport". Oder ist es nur umgangsprachlich?

Comment: Nur umgangssprachlich.

Answer (score 0):

Nein, man übt nicht Sport aus sondern **einen** Sport aus oder **eine** Sportart.

Aber man treibt Sport.

"Ich übe Fußball aus" würde niemand sagen.

"Ich übe die Sportart Fußball aus" klingt hölzern, könnte man aber schon sagen.

"Ich treibe Radsport" kann man sagen oder auch "ich treibe Gymnastik".